# How to implement a 'dynamic' drag and drop (like iOS/Android)?

Tags: drag-and-drop, codenameone

I would like to implement a 'dynamic' drag and drop in a list. By 'dynamic' I mean that in the list in which the drag is happening, there's an empty space below the dragged element which 'follows it' as you drag through the list (to make it visually obvious where the dropped element will end up in the list). Like what you see in iOS/Android apps supporting D&D.

What I've tried is to use Component.dragEnter to insert an empty Component with the size of the dragged element below the dragged compoment. And as the drag moves through the list, remove the old Component and insert a new one in the new position (explanation of why I create a new Component in next paragraph). However, with the dynamic updates that CN1 does while dragging, and my own updates when moving the empty Component, I just cannot find a way to make it work so I get the right vusual behavior. One aspect making this more complex than you'd think at first is that CN1's built-in support for drag&drop makes the original dragged component invisible with setVisible(false) which means it leaves an empty space behind.

The reason I recreate a new empty Component is because the final drop() will happen on the empty Component, and my trick to make this work is to override drop() on the empty Component to call drop on the dropTarget that is (was) in the Component's position.

All in all, I've spend I don't know how many days trying to get this to work with no success so far. Let me know if anyone has a suggestion for a more straightforward approach?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The builtin support hides the original component but drags an image of it which you can customize by overriding `getDragImage()`.

You can use custom code to highlight the drop location by using a drag over listener which you can accomplish by using `addDragOverListener(ActionListener)`.

Comment: Thanks, I know this part of the API, but I don't see how it can help achieve the effect of the 'empty' space below the dragged item. This video shows the effect I would like to implement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoTUAgPZE8w . I assume that there must be some way to do this in CN1, I just need to be pointed in the right direction :-)

Comment: Just add a blank component where the drop will be with the preferred size of your component. Then revalidate. When ready you can use replace to insert your component into that place.